# POSTGRESQL How to return multiple rows from SQL function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I'm new to databases and SQL and i've been messing around with functions on POSTGRESQL and I made a simple function to select all names from a table.

But the function, when called, returns just a single row as opposed to all rows being returned when i use `SELECT c_name FROM customers;` instead of the code shown below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_cust_names()
RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
SELECT c_name FROM customers;
$body$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Function call

`SELECT get_cust_names()`

this returns just a SINGLE row and this isnt code that i will use in a project etc. I'm just curious as to why postgresql behaves this way.

Comment: Because that is what you told it to do. If want to return more then one row then do as the docs says, [Return set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) or [Return table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the function as `returns table(..)`  or `returns setof`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_cust_names()
RETURNS table(cust_name varchar) 
AS
$body$
  SELECT c_name 
  FROM customers;
$body$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then use it like a table:

```
select *
from get_cust_names();
```